# how to subset data in R using conditional operation booleans

Tags: r, ggplot2, conditional-statements, boolean-logic, subset

I have a database containing two variable. I can make a scatter plot based on these two variables but now I want to specify a new range where y is between 0.35 and 1 and x is between 0.20 and 0.32.
how can I make a subset based on conditions above using boolean logics such as <, >, or= to.

Comment: The above duplicate is if you wanted to subset the data before passing it to `ggplot`. If you want to do the limits in `ggplot`, look at the `limits` arguments to `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` (or the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to `coord_cartesian`. Without a reproducible example, I'm just guessing at what you want.

Comment: Please read the question. my question is different since I am not interested multiple criteria, but I need to define new ranges using ><= operational booleans.